# using ports on localhost for WCF service

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, localhost, port

I have developed a WCF service which runs on port 8357 using net TCP binding. If the client of the service is on the same machine, do I need explicitly open 8357 port or it's not required since the client is on local host (I know it's very basic question but anyway..)?

Thanks in advance,
-Neel

Comment: What happens if you _try it_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is No, the client doesn't need to open a port.

Basically, the client never needs to open a port (i.e. create and register a listener) unless it's communicating with the host in duplex mode - i.e. communication initiated in both directions.

Of course there are all kinds of issues that can prevent communication between a WCF client and host, including firewalls, port rights, etc., but on the same machine you shouldn't have any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

By "open" do you mean allow connections to the port in a firewall? Whether you need to do that or not depends on which firewall you use and how it's configured, but typical configurations do allow connections from localhost to localhost by default.